# How I call my ownMethod in Popup Menu

Tags: java, android

i want to show listview in popupmenu ?
  i build initializeVars() method for listview 
  how icall this method on my showPopupMenu(View v)
  tell me solution of this program

```
public void initializeVars(){
    lv_sample = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_sample);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.setlanguage, R.id.tv_content, values);
    if(adapter==null) 
        return;
    lv_sample.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void showPopupMenu(View v){
    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, v);
    popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, popupMenu.getMenu());

    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, item.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }
});
popupMenu.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/pop1"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/hello_world"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/pop2"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/hello_world"/>
<item 
    android:id="@+id/pop3"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/hello_world"/>
```

inflating it with PopupMenu will by default show the items as list....

But if u still want to show a list then:

you can extend DialogFragment...

```
public class DefaultViewDialog extends DialogFragment{

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    //following commented code produces check box list in the dialog
    //dialogBuilder.setMultiChoiceItems(R.array.DefaultView_array, null, null);

    /* setItems(id) creates a simple list */
    dialogBuider.setItems(R.array.DefaultView_array, null, null);
    return dialogBuilder.create();

}
```

}

hoping that i helped :)